# "Product Mapping Applied Provider" field in ShipStation

Tags: mapping, field, product, orders

Perhaps someone tried to find information on how information is formed / configured / entered on the order in the "Product Mapping Applied Provider" field? From SS support, I have not yet been able to get a clear answer, unfortunately.